# Paste string if condition matches

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a small question regarding to paste function in r.
Here is my Table:

```
Name        Value
AA          0       
BB          1       
CC          0   
DD          1       
EE          1       
FF          1       
GG          0   
HH          1
```

What  I want to do is to get another column nameed `Category` in `Table`, depend on `Name` column in such a way that if `AA` or `BB` in column then in `Category` column must paste `Duke`, for `CC` category should be `Mike`,
for `DD` or `EE` category should be `Mark` and so on. In the End I should get 
a `Table`

```
Name      Value        Category
AA          0           Duke    
BB          1           Duke    
CC          0           Mike
DD          1           Mark    
EE          1           Mark    
FF          1           Tom 
GG          0           Hex
HH          1           Tom
```

`Table` is quite big and impossible to make it manually so is there any smart way to read `Name` column and paste in `Category` column? Any loop function or combination of loop and paste function in r ? I search on stackoverflow but couldn't find a similar case. What I was thinking is something like this:
`Table$Category <- within(Table,ifelse(Name=="AA" | Name== "BB",paste("Duke")), ifelse (Name=="CC" ,paste("Mike")), ifesle(Name=="DD" | Name== "EE",paste("Mark"))`
Can someone have a look over this? Thank you.

Comment: Your syntax is a bit off. It should go something like that: `df$Category <- with(df, ifelse(Name %in% c('AA', 'BB'), 'Duke', ifelse(Name == 'CC', 'Mike', ifelse(...))))`

Comment: Do you have a mapping of Names and Categories somewhere that can be used? If it's such a big table, it doesn't seem writing this command will be much faster?

Comment: You may want to look at `dplyr::case_when`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a named vector where you define the mapping. Example:

```
lookup_vector <- c(
  AA = "Duke",
  BB = "Duke",
  CC = "Mike",
  DD = "Mark",
  EE = "Mark",
  FF = "Tom",
  GG = "Hex",
  HH = "Tom"
)

Table[["Category"]] <- lookup_vector[Table[["Name"]]]

#   Name Value Category
# 1   AA     0     Duke
# 2   BB     1     Duke
# 3   CC     0     Mike
# 4   DD     1     Mark
# 5   EE     1     Mark
# 6   FF     1      Tom
# 7   GG     0      Hex
# 8   HH     1      Tom
```

Data:

```
Table <- data.frame(
  Name = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"), 
  Value = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using plyr's mapvalues but this is also good. `ifelse` is vectorized and if we nest the ifelse statements it could easily make the program slow.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a keyVal data.frame and then `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
 keyVal <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:8, .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC", 
  "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 
 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Duke", "Hex", "Mark", 
  "Mike", "Tom"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -8L))


library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, keyVal)
#  Name Value Category
#1   AA     0     Duke
#2   BB     1     Duke
#3   CC     0     Mike
#4   DD     1     Mark
#5   EE     1     Mark
#6   FF     1      Tom
#7   GG     0      Hex
#8   HH     1      Tom
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:8, .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC", 
 "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"), class = "factor"), Value = c(0L, 
 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -8L))
```